# Employee Manager Report - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the below table

```
empid   empname     managerID
1          A          NULL
2          B           1
3          C           1
4          D           2
```

The ddl is as under

```
Declare @t table(empid int, empname varchar(20), managerID int)
insert into @t 

select 1,'A',null union all
select 2,'B',1 union all
select 3,'C',1 union all 
select 4,'D',2
```

What I have to do is to prepare a report which will indicate which employees report to which manager.

I have soved it using

```
select EmpName = e.empname, ManagerName = m.empname
from @t e 
left join
@t m
on  e.managerID = m.empid
```

and the desired output being

```
EmpName    ManagerName
A          NULL
B          A
C          A
D          B
```

What are the other ways of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @t table(empid int, empname varchar(20), managerID int)

insert into @t 
select 1,'A',null union all
select 2,'B',1 union all
select 3,'C',1 union all 
select 4,'D',2

;with CTE AS
(
    Select empid,empname,managerID,
    Cast(empname As Varchar(max)) As ReportingManager
    from @T
    where managerID is null

    UNION ALL

    Select T.empid,T.empname,T.managerID,
    Cast(CTE.empname+'->'+t.empname As Varchar(max)) As ReportingManager
    from @T As T
    INNER JOIN CTE ON T.managerID=CTE.empid 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Hello, I used a very similar script to acheive what I was looking to do, it worked for most managers in my company but I came across 2 managers that are set to report to each other, therefor when I run for those specific managers, I get a Max Recursion Error being exhaused 100 times... is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your solution is most  appropriate, but we can rewrite it, e.g.:

```
select t1.empname [EmpName]
    , (select t2.empname from @t t2 where t2.empid = t1.managerID) [ManagerName]
from @t t1
```

Comment: Correct result, but in general you should join and avoid subqueries in select whenever possible

Comment: @niktrs, I agree. I wrote my opinion about best solution for OP's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Self join the table

case 1: all employees who have managers

```
select e1.empname employee, e2.empname manager
from employee e1
join employee e2 on e1.managerId = e2.empid
order by e2.name,e1.name
```

case 2: all employees who have managers or not

```
select e1.empname employee, COALESCE(e2.empname,'none') manager
from employee e1
left join employee e2 on e1.managerId = e2.empid
order by e2.name,e1.name
```

Comment: it produces wrong result. Use outer join instead of inner. And what the difference between your query and OP's?

Comment: I thought that you wanted only employees with managers. I wrote both options

Comment: I'm not topic starter :-) I only surmised.

Comment: @polishchuk your comment is good, so I thought it would be better to provide both cases and let @aditi decide what's better for him

Comment: I agree with you, that's ok :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you asked for other ways.   This is a little freaky.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (empid int, empname varchar(20), managerID int)
GO
insert into employee 

select 1,'A',null union all
select 2,'B',1 union all
select 3,'C',1 union all 
select 4,'D',2
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeeTree](@ManagerId int)
RETURNS XML
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
BEGIN RETURN 
  (SELECT   empID as '@Id', 
            empname AS '@Name',
            dbo.GetEmployeeTree(empid) 
   FROM employee em
   WHERE ManagerId=@ManagerId
   FOR XML PATH('Employee'), TYPE)
END

GO
SELECT  empID as '@Id', 
        empname AS '@Name',
        dbo.GetEmployeeTree(empId) 
FROM employee
WHERE managerId is null
FOR XML PATH('Employee'), ROOT('Employees')
```

Which gives this output

```
<Employees>
  <Employee Id="1" Name="A">
    <Employee Id="2" Name="B">
      <Employee Id="4" Name="D" />
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="3" Name="C" />
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I have actually used this to generate large XML trees with tens of thousands of nodes and it is quite quick.  There is probably a way to merge the root query with the child query, I just haven't quite figured that out yet.  When I have used this technique in the past I have used a separate link and node table to define the hierarchy and it works a bit cleaner  when you do that.

Comment: "This is a little freaky." -- You never fail to disappoint, my friend :).