# About SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Employee Manager Report - Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546640/employee-manager-report-sql-server)

I have an `Employee` table like this:

```
Eno Ename   Mangerid
1    X      Null
2    Y      1
3    Z      2
```

but I want result as shown below

```
Ename    Managername
X        Null
Y        X
Z        y
```

Can anyone give me the answer for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something you might be interested in is nested sets.  Joe Celko has some really good articles on it.   see: (Trees in SQL) http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select 
    e.Ename,
    m.Ename as ManagerName
from employee e
left join employee m on e.ManagerId = m.Eno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.Ename employee, e2.Ename manager
from employee e1
join employee e2 on e1.ManagerId = e2.Eno
```

Comment: thanks, But It gives the result as  Y X and Z Y

Answer (score 0):

Use Self Join on  Employee Table

```
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.ENAME as EmployeeName, EMPLOYEE.ENO as ManagerName
 FROM EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS EMPLOYEE_1 
ON EMPLOYEE.ENO = EMPLOYEE_1.MANEGERID
```

---

Comment: thanks, But It gives the result as  Y X and Z Y

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recursive CTE

[Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

This you'll get as deeped in the hierarchy as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select e.Name, (select m.name from Employee M where M.Eno =e.Mangerid) as Manager
from Employee e
```